# \t in conky shows another character

Tags: lua, cairo, conky

When I use `\t` in conky, another character appears on the screen.

[image]

Here's what I've used:

```
 text = 'Uploaded: ' .. conky_parse('${totalup wlp2s0}') .. '\tSpeed: ' .. conky_parse('${upspeed wlp2s0}')
```

And I used `cairo_show_text()` function to show the text on the screen.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [cairographics](https://www.cairographics.org/manual/cairo-text.html) says,

> The functions with text in their name form cairo's toy text API

and its limited functionality is for testing and demos. You will have to do your own work to implement a *tab stop* by drawing the text, not including the tab character, then reposition the current point to the fixed position you want as tab stop, and draw the rest of the text.

Answer (score 2):

http://conky.sourceforge.net/variables.html

Use `goto` to start the next character at position x.